# How can I ensure a PayPal payment bounces back to my website to immediately credit a user?

Tags: paypal

Well I am working on a site that basically accepts PayPal payments to give their accounts a premium status, don't need to get into exact details of what it does but what I am trying to accomplish is to have a "Pay Now with PayPal" button that will accept the payment then bounce them back to my site with some kind of verification code so I can say "Okay, paid let me run this code to set your account to premium"

Any idea how I can do this?  I can specify a success URL but it requires a user to click a button saying "Return to *" after they pay and even that gives them a scary warning message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.paypal.com/ipn

Comment: Yes that's the thing I couldn't remember :)